# Launching a program from a server on an intranet

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so I know you don't normally want people to be able to execute programs from a server, but that's what I'd like to do. I've got it to the point where I can execute the program if it is installed on the local computer WHILE I am running from the local client machine (using VS 2010). If I try to run it from the server, I get a "System cannot find file" error. Here is the code that I can get to run if running from the local client machine:

```
Protected Sub BeginTutorial(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Savvy Training Tutorials\Word 2010\Savvy's Word 2010 Tutorial Menu.exe"
    psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName)
    Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
End Sub
```

I've also got the program installed on the server, so if I change the file path, it gives me the above mentioned "cannot find file" error. I've tried installing the file either to the default location on the server, or also within the directory containing the website. Below are the two examples:

Default Install:

```
Protected Sub BeginTutorial(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Savvy Training Tutorials\Word 2010\Savvy's Word 2010 Tutorial Menu.exe"
    psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName)
    Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
End Sub
```

Install to directory containing website:

```
Protected Sub BeginTutorial(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.FileName = "E:\intranet\Word 2010\Savvy's Word 2010 Tutorial Menu.exe"
    psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName)
    Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
End Sub
```

I've also tried taking out the apostrophe and that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at PSExec http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: You _do_ realize that the client and server computers are not the same computer, and won't have the same programs on their disk? Also, that if the program is run from ASP.NET codebehind, the client will never see the program output? Just making sure. It wasn't clear in your question.

Comment: Hey @JohnSaunders, I put up three different versions of code, the last two versions of code are meant to point to the server. The first segment of code is for when I press Debug button and it opens up in the browser as "localhost..." And the file that it is supposed to open is an executable, which will then open a program.

Comment: Hey @MikeCheel, it looks like the PSExec tool would start the program on the server, but not show it on the client machine? Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize you were trying to view it locally. That's something that citrix does. I don't know if it is really possible to do that without special software.